# port .net framework to .net core while sharing source code for backward support

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

We have several different products compiled for .net framework 4.6.1. Each of these products contains several different solutions which contains many projects that are co-dependent between different solution and products. We need to port one of these products to .net core 2.0. The recommended way by Microsoft to port a .net framework project to .net core is to simply copy all the code file to a new .net core project. Since we have hundreds of projects I need to port to .net core, and at the same time these projects needs to be referenced by legacy .net framework projects, I prefer a solution that would allow me to use the same CS files and only to compile them using different .csproj files. Otherwise, it would just be impossible to maintain all of it. Logically it's not supposed to be very difficult as long as I keep the code valid in both frameworks, but I cant find a clean way to do it in Visual Studio.
Any suggestions for the best approach to this problem?

Comment: Target .NET Standard and then you get it.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something important, but I dont see that option in existing projects. I see it only in new projects created already targeting .Net standart

Comment: Yes. You need to create new projects targeting .NET Standard (1.3 or 2.0), and then cut and paste the source files.

Comment: That is not what I need, "I prefer a solution that would allow me to use the same CS files and only to compile them using different .csproj files. Otherwise, it would just be impossible to maintain all of it". I need backward compatibility , and i need to maintain only one code base. it doesn't make any sense to copy and paste the same code, why wouldn't different compilers use the same files?

Comment: "That's not what I need“. What have you tried and read? Without any experiments, it is ridiculous to say [what is so common today](https://blog.lextudio.com/tips-for-net-nuget-package-authors-august-2017-48f07604e4a0) is not what you need.

Comment: hmmm. Now I understand your first answer. I didnt know .net framework can reference .net standard projects. Thanks a lot!